# Im getting java.lang.StackOverflowError while running my project?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, solrj

I'm trying to implement solr search with Spring and postgres using maven but on running the appilcation i get 404 with the exception

```
Exception processing loader WebappLoader[/solrjExample] background process
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

I really don't understand what is the problem Here is my spring-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  "
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:solr="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/solr/spring-solr.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.tcs.com.controller" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:org/tcs/com/lak/resources/application.properties" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                    <!-- <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" 
                        /> -->
                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                    <property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- ##################################### SOLR ##################################### -->
    <!-- Configures HTTP Solr server -->
    <solr:solr-server id="solrServer" url="${solr.server.url}" />

    <!-- Configures Solr template -->
    <bean id="solrTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="solrServer" />
    </bean>
<!-- ##################################### postgres ##################################### -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        p:url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Prime" p:username="postgres"
        p:password="Password" /> 
        <!-- ##################################### Hibernate ##################################### -->
    <bean id="sessionfactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:Hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean> 
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionfactory" />
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

And my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <display-name>solrjExample</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>solrjExample</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>WEB-INF/slorjExample-servlet.xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>solrjExample</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I think there is something wrong with the configuration or something as i am new to solr.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: check your code, there may be some infinite loop of infinite recursion

Comment: @Jayant Actually its not running itself when i try to run itself i get this error before i do any operation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics behind this error was the use the use of both **Solrj** and **Spring-data-solr** it is basically because of the logger used in these API's call each other recursively until the stack overflow error is thrown bring down the tomcat. So i removed the spring-data-solr  dependency from my pom.

```
The purpose of slf4j-jcl module is to delegate or redirect calls made to an SLF4J logger to jakarta commons logging (JCL). 

The purpose of the jcl-over-slf4j module is to redirect calls made to a JCL logger to SLF4J.

 If both slf4j-jcl.jar and jcl-over-slf4j.jar are present on the class path, then a StackOverflowError will inevitably occur immediately after the first invocation of an SLF4J or a JCL logger.
```

The problem is described in the link http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

Trying to find if there is a workaround for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this kind of error is due to a recursive infinite loop. Do you have some own code executed at server startup ?

Comment: noo i do not have any own code executed actually in maven pom i have added the solrj dependency and also the solr core dependency... ya im understanding there is some infiniteloop but no able to identify because of what check my configuartions is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say you run your application ? Are you running some sort of searching or you mean when the welcome page is loading ?
Is there a specific page you access by default when you *run your application* ?
Did you try and put some debug points in the piece of code which runs when you start up your application ? 
Or do you mean you get this error when you start your server after deploying your application ?

Comment: At running means when the welcome page is loading no default page is accessed... there is no code that is run.. i just give run on my applicaton in eclipse when i get a 404 or unable to display page error with this error along with no able to start tomcat v7.

Comment: You should comment some config to identify which combination make your server crash at startup, then maybe open a defect on one or both technologies

Comment: @Gab I tried removing the solr-core dependency i dont get server crash but i get this following error... org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'solr:solr-server'.