# Difference between solr core & solrj & spring-data-solr

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

I have been trying to learn solr for implementing search for one of the application. There are three different libraries that i always bump into **solr-core**, **solrj**, and **spring-data-solr** what is the basic difference between three three jar and which is supposed to be used with spring? Recently i tried using solrj and solr-core with spring and got an `StackOverflowException`

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240085/im-getting-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-while-running-my-project) is my question that resulted in stack overflow.Unable to find a solution  i tried removing solr-core dependency and ended up in the following error

```
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'solr:solr-server'.
```

I basically feel that im not doing it the right way.
An eye opener for my confusion will be quite helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Solrj is the client lib when trying to connect to a SolrServer instance.

Spring Data Solr is a small layer above solrj providing some fluent API and repository abstractions.
Have a look at the [example](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-solr-examples/) and/or this [tutorial](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/solr/spring-data-solr-tutorial-query-methods/) as a starting point.

You might want to use solr-core to run an embedded SolrServer eg. for testing.

Comment: Chirstoph strobl i tried doing an example with solrj and solr-core alone and ended in StackOverflowException which i am still not able to figure out why can you check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240085/im-getting-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-while-running-my-project